# How to play audio from a URL in React Native app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo-av, react-native-sound

I have been trying to play the audio from a Youtube video (or .mp3 URL) in my React Native app. For my purposes, I cannot download the audio files to my device, they need to be streamed from the internet. I tried both Expo AV and React-Native-Sound-Player libraries but none were able to play the audio.

For testing the URL I am using is: https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3.

When I go to use the loadUrl() function in React-Native-Sound-Player, I get an error saying "Cannot read property 'loadUrl' of null". Same issue with play URL.

Does anyone have any experience streaming an audio from a URL in their apps? Is it even possible?

Any advice is appreciated.

Using this block of code to store the mp3 file in "currentSong" results in the error [TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadUrl' of null].

```
 try {
  currentSong = SoundPlayer.loadUrl('https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3');
 } catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
```

I also tried using the react-native-video library and used the following code to no avail:

```
<Video source = {{uri: "https://storage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"}}
                ref={(ref) => {
                  this.player = ref
                }}                                      // Store reference
                onBuffer={this.onBuffer}                // Callback when remote video is buffering
                onError={this.videoError}               // Callback when video cannot be loaded
                style = {styles.video} />
```

I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constants' of null

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I am trying `expo-av`, but it doesn't work either - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76706375

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-native-track-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-track-player) library for audio player.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether yours issue has resolved or not but one solution that I tried on your problem and it is working fine on my side,
You need to use SoundPlayer.playUrl(url) instead of loadUrl()

Try this :

```
  try {
  currentSong = SoundPlayer.playUrl('https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3');
 } catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
```

loadUrl() did something different as stated by author of the package

> loadUrl(url: string) Load the audio from the given url without playing
> it. You can then play the audio by calling play(). This might be
> useful when you find the delay between calling playUrl() and the sound
> actually starts playing is too much.

Answer (score -1):

;Hi! Try to use `expo-av` library: `https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/av/`

Comment: Hi! Does it work for you? I posted this question because `expo-av` doesn't work for me :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76706375